# valgrind detect memory leak after asprintf call even when free was called

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

My code looks like this:

```
bool
amflinkd_apteryx_set_action (const char *address, char *action)
{
    bool ret = false;
    char *path = NULL;

    if (asprintf (&path, "%s/%s", AMFLINKD_IP_ADDRESS_PATH, address) > 0)
    {
        ret = apteryx_set_string (path, "action", action);
    }

    free (path);
    return ret;
}
```

Then I run my unit test on it which execute valgrind on it. My output is:

```
np: running: "amflinkd_apteryx_unit_tests.amflinkd_apteryx_set_action_true"
EVENT SLMATCH err: SET: Not initialised
at 0x805B512: np::spiegel::describe_stacktrace (np/spiegel/spiegel.cxx)
by 0x804BAD3: np::event_t::with_stack (np/event.cxx)
by 0x8067688: np::mock_syslog (isyslog.c)
by 0x8079EA8: np::spiegel::platform::intercept_tramp (np/spiegel/platform/linux_x86.cxx)
by 0x412BC71:

==4== 33 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 323 of 525
==4==    at 0x402B19B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==4==    by 0x47ECAA7: vasprintf (vasprintf.c:73)
==4==    by 0x47CFEEA: asprintf (asprintf.c:35)
==4==    by 0x804B392: amflinkd_apteryx_set_action (amflinkd_apteryx.c:33)
==4==    by 0x804B28F: test_amflinkd_apteryx_set_action_true (amflinkd_apteryx_unit_tests.c:38)
==4==    by 0x805B0F1: np::spiegel::function_t::invoke(std::vector<np::spiegel::value_t, std::allocator<np::spiegel::value_t> >) const (spiegel.cxx:606)
==4==    by 0x804F68A: np::runner_t::run_function(np::functype_t, np::spiegel::function_t*) (runner.cxx:526)
==4==    by 0x804FEF6: np::runner_t::run_test_code(np::job_t*) (runner.cxx:650)
==4==    by 0x805019D: np::runner_t::begin_job(np::job_t*) (runner.cxx:710)
==4==    by 0x804E694: np::runner_t::run_tests(np::plan_t*) (runner.cxx:147)
==4==    by 0x8050374: np_run_tests (runner.cxx:822)
==4==    by 0x804BA7D: main (main.c:108)
==4== 
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: definite
   fun:malloc
   fun:vasprintf
   fun:asprintf
   fun:amflinkd_apteryx_set_action
   fun:test_amflinkd_apteryx_set_action_true
   fun:_ZNK2np7spiegel10function_t6invokeESt6vectorINS0_7value_tESaIS3_EE
   fun:_ZN2np8runner_t12run_functionENS_10functype_tEPNS_7spiegel10function_tE
   fun:_ZN2np8runner_t13run_test_codeEPNS_5job_tE
   fun:_ZN2np8runner_t9begin_jobEPNS_5job_tE
   fun:_ZN2np8runner_t9run_testsEPNS_6plan_tE
   fun:np_run_tests
   fun:main
}
==4== 40 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 335 of 525
==4==    at 0x402B19B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==4==    by 0x47ECAA7: vasprintf (vasprintf.c:73)
==4==    by 0x47CFEEA: asprintf (asprintf.c:35)
==4==    by 0x412D10B: apteryx_cas_string (apteryx.c:530)
==4==    by 0x412D1BC: apteryx_set_string (apteryx.c:544)
==4==    by 0x804B3B0: amflinkd_apteryx_set_action (amflinkd_apteryx.c:35)
==4==    by 0x804B28F: test_amflinkd_apteryx_set_action_true (amflinkd_apteryx_unit_tests.c:38)
==4==    by 0x805B0F1: np::spiegel::function_t::invoke(std::vector<np::spiegel::value_t, std::allocator<np::spiegel::value_t> >) const (spiegel.cxx:606)
==4==    by 0x804F68A: np::runner_t::run_function(np::functype_t, np::spiegel::function_t*) (runner.cxx:526)
==4==    by 0x804FEF6: np::runner_t::run_test_code(np::job_t*) (runner.cxx:650)
==4==    by 0x805019D: np::runner_t::begin_job(np::job_t*) (runner.cxx:710)
==4==    by 0x804E694: np::runner_t::run_tests(np::plan_t*) (runner.cxx:147)
==4== 
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Leak
   match-leak-kinds: definite
   fun:malloc
   fun:vasprintf
   fun:asprintf
   fun:apteryx_cas_string
   fun:apteryx_set_string
   fun:amflinkd_apteryx_set_action
   fun:test_amflinkd_apteryx_set_action_true
   fun:_ZNK2np7spiegel10function_t6invokeESt6vectorINS0_7value_tESaIS3_EE
   fun:_ZN2np8runner_t12run_functionENS_10functype_tEPNS_7spiegel10function_tE
   fun:_ZN2np8runner_t13run_test_codeEPNS_5job_tE
   fun:_ZN2np8runner_t9begin_jobEPNS_5job_tE
   fun:_ZN2np8runner_t9run_testsEPNS_6plan_tE
}
EVENT VALGRIND 73 bytes of memory leaked


EVENT VALGRIND 2 unsuppressed errors found by valgrind


FAIL amflinkd_apteryx_unit_tests.amflinkd_apteryx_set_action_true
```

The first leak is supposedly the "path" pointer, but I do free it before returning.
I've got no idea what the second leak is.

This is the unit test function calling the amflinkd_apteryx_set_action() function :

```
void
test_amflinkd_apteryx_set_action_true (void)
{
    printf("Running test_amflinkd_apteryx_set_action_true test.");
    const char *address = {"192.168.1.5"};
    char *action = {"drop"};
    bool res = amflinkd_apteryx_set_action (address, action);
    NP_ASSERT_TRUE (res);
}
```

Here is the code for apteryx_set_string()

```
bool
apteryx_cas_string (const char *path, const char *key, const char *value, uint64_t ts)
{
    char *full_path;
    size_t len;
    bool res = false;

    /* Create full path */
    if (key)
        len = asprintf (&full_path, "%s/%s", path, key);
    else
        len = asprintf (&full_path, "%s", path);
    if (len)
    {
        res = apteryx_cas (full_path, value, ts);
        free (full_path);
    }
    return res;
}

bool
apteryx_set_string (const char *path, const char *key, const char *value)
{
    return apteryx_cas_string (path, key, value, UINT64_MAX);
}
```

I retried my amflinkd_apteryx_set_action():

```
bool
amflinkd_apteryx_set_action (const char *address, char *action)
{
    bool ret = false;
    char *path = NULL;

    if (asprintf (&path, "%s/%s", AMFLINKD_IP_ADDRESS_PATH, address) > 0)
    {
        ret = true; //apteryx_set_string (path, "action", action);
    }

    free (path);
    return ret;
}
```

This passed without a memory leak.
Then I tried :

```
bool
amflinkd_apteryx_set_action (const char *address, char *action)
{
    bool ret = false;
    char *path = NULL;

    if (asprintf (&path, "%s/%s", AMFLINKD_IP_ADDRESS_PATH, address) > 0)
    {
        ret = apteryx_test_string (path, "action", action);
    }

    free (path);
    return ret;
}
```

with

```
bool
apteryx_test_string (const char *path, const char *key, const char *value)
{
    char *full_path;
    size_t len;
    bool res = false;

    /* Create full path */
    if (key)
        len = asprintf (&full_path, "%s/%s", path, key);
    else
        len = asprintf (&full_path, "%s", path);
    if (len)
    {
        res = true;
        free (full_path);
    }
    return res;
}
```

This also passed without a memory leak. It must be something in apteryx_set_string() that prevents the memory from being freed or the references are lost.

I figured it out!
The code was hitting an ASSERT

`ASSERT ((ref_count > 0), return false, "SET: Not initialised\n");`

two calls deeper in the apteryx_set_string() function. Because of the assert the free was not called and valgrind picked that up as a memory leak.
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: With this code `path` shouldn't be loss you free it, unless `apteryx_set_string` `exit()` the program.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. This is the unit test function calling the amflinkd_apteryx_set_action() function :
`    void
    test_amflinkd_apteryx_set_action_true (void)
    {
     printf("Running test_amflinkd_apteryx_set_action_true test.");
     const char *address = {"192.168.1.5"};
     char *action = {"drop"};
     bool res = amflinkd_apteryx_set_action (address, action);
     NP_ASSERT_TRUE (res);
    }
`

Comment: I don't think this explains the problem you're asking about, but your code for checking `asprintf`'s return value is wrong in both cases. `asprintf` returns `-1` on error, not `0`.

Comment: Did you redefine `free` anywhere in your code?

Comment: No, I tested free with a simple char *str = (char *)calloc(10, sizeof(char)); statement, and it worked fine. Valgrind detected leak if str wasn't freed, and detected no leak if str were freed.

Comment: OK, then I'll wait for the MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!
The code was hitting an ASSERT

`ASSERT ((ref_count > 0), return false, "SET: Not initialised\n");`

two calls deeper in the apteryx_set_string() function. Because of the assert the free was not called and valgrind picked that up as a memory leak.
Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score -1):

It's possibly a scoping issue. Try freeing inside the if block.

Variables creating inside an if statement, to my recollection, only live inside the if block. Thus, you'd have lost it by the closing brace of the if block.

While you declared the variable outside of the block, the allocation didn't happen until the asprintf() call during the if statement.

**Edit**
To provide more info, my thought is that asprintf is the one that declares the *actual* variable that the pointer it is given is simply pointed to. If this is the case, then the declaration of the variable that gets lost IS within the if statement

**Second Edit**
I tested with the following and could not reproduce:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void test() {
  char *str = NULL;

  if (asprintf(&str, "%s", "foo") > 0) {
    printf("%s\n", str);
  }

  free(str);
}

int main() {
  test();
  return 0;
}
```

GCC command line:

```
gcc -g -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include asprintf.c
```

Output:

```
valgrind ./a.out
==2461== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2461== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2461== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2461== Command: ./a.out
==2461==
foo
==2461==
==2461== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2461==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2461==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 1,128 bytes allocated
==2461==
==2461== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2461==
==2461== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2461== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: There are no variables created in that block.

Comment: See my edit. He allocated during asprintf. Otherwise, yes, you're correct

Comment: So? Allocation is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm not at home presently but I'll try this case in a little bit when I get back.

Comment: I tested the free command inside and out side the if statement with no difference.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll play with it when I get home and see if I can find a better answer for you

Comment: @user211096, I edited and posted what I thought would be a reproducible test but it didn't reproduce. Care to edit and try to reproduce with it?